# SQL Syntax Using PHP Join

Tags: php, sql

Database query is failing most certainly due to a syntax error below. 
Does anyone see the error? I'd appreciate it. 
Thanks,
Chris

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ".self::$table_name." (";
$sql .= join(", ", array_keys($attributes));
$sql .= ") VALUES ('";
$sql .= join("', '", array_values($attributes));
$sql .= "')";
```

Comment: what does the $sql variable contain after you run this?  Also what is the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: Are you looking for [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html) ?

Comment: The query looks fine. What error are you getting?

Comment: What's the SQL error? Assuming you aren't using any reserved SQL keywords, `self::$table_name` is a valid table name and `$attributes` is an associative array it should be fine.

Comment: @Chris Mazzochi try doing what I recommended in my answer and let me know the output of `echo $sql`

Comment: You should be escaping properly, and/or using prepared statements as `$attributes` could contain a single quote or be empty, etc. Don't generate queries like this, it's terrible logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your previous code would evaluate to an sql statement similar to:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tableName (1,2,3,4) VALUES ('a','b','c','d')";
```

The string should not fail if the keys in `$attribute` are actually the columns in your database, and if the datatypes of the values in `$attribute` are in the necessary format of their respective columns.

Seeing that your sql query failed, one of the previous 2 conditions is probably false. You should try commenting out the execution of the query, and temporarily use the code `echo $sql`, that way you'll be able to identify what part of your code is causing the error.

Comment: It is probably one of two problems -- one of the fields is not a string or the $attributes includes a generated key. (eg "ID")

Comment: @Hogan yeah probably, and it's super easy to find out by just printing out `$sql` on the screen :), though it seems he forgot all about his Stackoverflow question :(

Comment: Haven't forgotten. It's sleep time where I live. I'll pick it up when I wake up. Thanks so far...

Comment: @ChrisMazzochi alright. Im going to sleep now too. good luck with it dude.

Comment: @Webeng: Thank you.  Inspecting the $sql variable showed me what my syntax errors were.  I appreciate your taking the time.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone that took the time to think about this.  And to all who suggested inspecting the $sql variable to find out what my syntax errors were, that worked.

I am grateful, now I can move on. 
Thanks,
Chris